# Python, Flask работа с множествами форм и checked

Tags: html, python, flask

Не могу понять, как в Python для Flask написать следующие. У нас есть 4 `input` формы, `_f1`, `_f2`, `_f3` и `_f4`. Мы можем получить данные в питон через `_f1 = request.form['_f1']`.

Если мой код выглядит вот так:

```
@app.route('/form_test', methods=['POST'])
def _form_test():
    _f1 = request.form['_f1']
    _f2 = request.form['_f2']
    _f3 = request.form['_f3']
    _f4 = request.form['_f4']
    #Выполнить потом что-то
```

То должны быть переданы все 4 формы, иначе получаю ошибку. Как сделать различие между тем, сколько данных переданы и какой из будущих `if` значений, должно быть выполнено - если переданы к примеру только в `_f1` и `_f2` значение, а остальные остались пустые. И еще предположим, у нас одна из форм это `radio` значение в `html`, как сделать различие между, `checked` и `unchecked`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже точно не помню , но помню смысл , сначала ты ифом проверяешь наличие самой формы

```
if ur_form is not None:
  do some job
```

Потом ты можешь считать множество , ну и дальше начинай дебажить принтами логерами , если не ошибаюсь ты можешь написать читлюбой ИД или же все форми или все инпуты.

```
radio = request.POST.getlist('ID_ELEMENT')
```

Comment: можно более подробнее?